# What's wrong with this RegEx?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to implement this in a small ruby script, and tested it on http://www.rubular.com/, where it worked perfectly. Not sure why its not performing in the actual script.

**The RegEx:** /(motion|links|sound|button|symbol)|(0.\d{8})|(\s\d{1}\s)|(\d{10}\s)/

**The Text it's Against:**

Trial ID: 1 | Trial Type: motion | Trick? 1
Click Time: 0.87913100 1302969732

Trial ID: 7 | Trial Type: button | Trick? 0
Click Time: 0.19817800 1302987043

etc. etc.

**What I am trying to grab:** Only the numbers, and the single word after "Trial Type". So for the first line of the example, I would only want " 1 motion 1 0.87913100 1302969732" to be returned. I also want to keep the space before the first number in each trial.

**My short ruby script**:

```
File.open('log.txt', 'r') do |file|
  contents = file.readlines.to_s
  regex = Regexp.new(/(motion|links|sound|button|symbol)|(0\.\d{8})|(\s\d{1}\s)|(\d{10}\s)/)
  matchdata = regex.match(contents).to_a
  matchdata.each do |match|
    if match != nil
      puts match
    end
  end
end
```

It only outputs two "1"s though. Hmm... I know its reading the file contents right, and when I tried an alternate simplet regex it worked fine.

Thanks for any help I get here!! : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the literal pipes inside the regex, fill in other missing literals (like Trick, \?, Click\sTime:, remove some of the spaces, etc...), and insert regex spaces where appropriate... i.e.

`regex = Regexp.new(/(motion|links|sound|button|symbol)\s\|\sTrick\?\s*\d\s*Click\s+Time:\s+(0\.\d{,8})\s(\d{10}))/)`

EDIT: fixed parenthesis nesting in the original

Comment: Oh, I'm not trying to get all the text out actually - I'm just trying to get the numbers and the single word after "trial type". Should have mentioned this originally, sorry!

Comment: @Jeff, that's exactly my point... the word after trial type and the numbers have many more things the re must match on.  You can't pretend they aren't there... `ruby` certainly wont.

Comment: Oh, I definitely am having trouble understanding regular expression then - I'm not exactly sure how to edit the expression to account for these, but not include them in the results...

Comment: @Jeff Escalante, the parenthesis provide match group results... the other stuff is there to help the regex engine keep its bearings. If you match early on the left side of a string, the engine moves right looking for more match results... if it sees things that are not in your regex, it barfs... that's why you still need to include characters that you won't actually assign to a variable later. The cheap way of doing this is to use `.+?` in most languages... I can't remember offhand how ruby would handle that and don't have the interpreter installed on this laptop... I chose to be explicit

Comment: thanks so much, with your help and the other answers I managed to finally solve the problem. The regex I needed is as such, for reference: Regexp.new(/.*?Trial ID: (\d+).*?Trial Type: (motion|links).*?Trick\? (\d+).*?Click Time: (0\.\d{8})\s(\d{10})/)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181)

```
 matchdata = contents.scan(regex)
```

Also @Mike Penington is correct, you shouldn't have to do the `if match != nil` if you do it right. You have to clean up your regex as well. The pipe character in regex is a special character to denote match the left side OR the right side, and you have the litteral pipe character that you must escape.

Comment: This helps a ton, thanks. Why does scan make such a difference? Also, this way I keep getting empty array results. I know this is probably because I am just bad at regular expressions, but if I could just eliminate blank array spots it would totally solve my problems... do you know how I'd do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the data follows a particular pattern, you can just follow that pattern in the regex, and pick up the portions you want with `(  )`.

```
/Trial ID: (\d+) \| Trial Type: (\w+) \| Trick\? (\d+) Click Time: ([\.\d]+) ([\.\d]+)/
```

The more you know previously about the data, the more specifically you can make the regex.
If you see some variations in the data, and the regex fails to match, then just relax the pattern:

- If the Trail ID, Trail ID may include a decimal point, use `[\.\d]+` instead of `\d+`.
- If the space can be more than one, then replace it with `[]+`
- If the space can be a tab, or can be absent, use `\s*` or `[ \t]*`.
- If the `Trial ID:` part may appear as a different phrase, replace it with `.*?`,

and so on.

If you are not sure how many spaces/tabs appear, use this:

```
/Trial\s*ID:\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*Trial\s*Type:\s*(\w+)\s*\|\s*Trick\?\s*(\d+)\s*Click\s*Time:\s*([\.\d]+)\s+([\.\d]+)/
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. So only what you put in parentheses is actually picked up by the regex? I didn't realize this haha. I input the pattern you put in here, which makes sense, and got no results though... hmm...

Comment: Then, maybe the string has some variations. For example, you might have two spaces instead of one, or even none, or you may have a tab. You may not have a colon, etc. Can you figure out what kind of variations your string has? What you didn't put in the parentheses will appear as part of `$0`, which represents the whole part that matched. Other parts in parentheses will be in `$1`, `$2`, ... respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help and that of others, I solved it. Here was my final regex: Regexp.new(/.*?Trial ID: (\d+).*?Trial Type: (motion|links).*?Trick\? (\d+).*?Click Time: (0\.\d{8})\s(\d{10})/)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times that trying to everything in a big regex makes you work too hard. Simplify things:

```
ary = [
  'Trial ID: 1 | Trial Type: motion | Trick? 1 Click Time: 0.87913100 1302969732',
  'Trial ID: 7 | Trial Type: button | Trick? 0 Click Time: 0.19817800 1302987043'
]

ary.each do |li|
  numbers = li.scan(/[\d.]+/)
  trial_type = li[/Trial Type: (\w+)/, 1]

  puts "%d %s %d %f %d\n" % [numbers.first, trial_type, *numbers[1 .. -1]]
end
# >> 1 motion 1 0.879131 1302969732
# >> 7 button 0 0.198178 1302987043
```

Regex patterns are powerful, but people think it's macho to do everything in one big line. You have to weigh doing that with the increased work necessary to put together the regex in the first place, plus maintain it if something changes in the text being parsed later.